# Пересчёт колонки исходя из значений в других колонках, аналог суммеслимн из Excel

Tags: python, pandas

Есть набор данных (см ниже). Изначально есть колонка `Traffic Share`, там посчитана доля каждой строки в рамках месяца (т.е. внутри месяца 100%). Мне необходимо рассчитать колонку в которой будут доли в разрезе `Time Period/Source Type from Overview` - сейчас эти данные посчитаны в колонке `Share from SourceType`.

Поясню на примере первых двух строк - для получения 58% надо 49% разделить на сумму всех черных в рамках мая (т.е. 49+36+0+0+0+0), для второй строки надо 39 разделить на туже сумму. И так далее.

в Excel вопрос решается делением строки на `суммеслимн` по колонке месяц и категория.

Повторяющиеся строки объясняются тем, что есть другие колонки, за счёт которых достигается уникальность строк, поэтому группировкой решить этот вопрос не получается.

```
Time Period;Source Type from Overview;Traffic Share;Sites;Share from SourceType
01.05.2017;Черный;0,4937672;чай;0,5790274
01.05.2017;Черный;0,3576897;чай;0,4194529
01.05.2017;Зеленый;0,099872;чай;1
01.05.2017;Белый;0,0332907;чай;1
01.05.2017;Красный;0,0120724;чай;0,8571429
01.05.2017;Красный;0,0020121;чай;0,1428571
01.05.2017;Черный;0,001296;чай;0,0015198
01.05.2017;Черный;0;чай;0
01.05.2017;Черный;0;чай;0
01.06.2017;Черный;0,624053;чай;0,6666667
01.06.2017;Черный;0,3105886;чай;0,3317972
01.06.2017;Зеленый;0,0553977;чай;1
01.06.2017;Белый;0,0085227;чай;1
01.06.2017;Черный;0,0014379;чай;0,0015361
01.06.2017;Красный;0;чай;0
01.06.2017;Красный;0;чай;0
01.06.2017;Черный;0;чай;0
01.06.2017;Зеленый;0;чай;0
01.07.2017;Черный;0,4464541;чай;0,5355872
01.07.2017;Черный;0,3871247;чай;0,4644128
01.07.2017;Зеленый;0,1134021;чай;1
01.07.2017;Порошковый;0,0265096;чай;1
01.07.2017;Красный;0,0132548;чай;1
01.07.2017;Белый;0,0132548;чай;1
01.07.2017;Черный;0;чай;0
01.07.2017;Зеленый;0;чай;0
```

Comment: вы можете привести небольшой пример данных в виде текста, CSV или Python кода, чтобы его можно было скопировать? Или выложить Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник? [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU да, конечно, файл [по ссылке](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MhkXmvPpo5rx43qCbmXZ16B3eZaKI2Tt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтение CSV в DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\example.csv', sep=';', decimal=',', 
                 encoding='cp1251', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=['Time Period'])
```

Группировка по `['Sites','Source Type from Overview', месяцу]` и подсчет `Share/month`:

```
df['Share/month'] = (df.groupby(['Sites',
                                 'Source Type from Overview',
                                 pd.Grouper(key='Time Period', freq='1MS')])
                       ['Traffic Share']
                       .transform(lambda x: x/x.sum()))
```

---

Результат:

```
In [267]: df
Out[267]:
   Time Period Source Type from Overview  Traffic Share Sites  Share from SourceType  Share/month
0   2017-05-01                    Черный       0.493767   чай               0.579027     0.579027
1   2017-05-01                    Черный       0.357690   чай               0.419453     0.419453
2   2017-05-01                   Зеленый       0.099872   чай               1.000000     1.000000
3   2017-05-01                     Белый       0.033291   чай               1.000000     1.000000
4   2017-05-01                   Красный       0.012072   чай               0.857143     0.857141
5   2017-05-01                   Красный       0.002012   чай               0.142857     0.142859
6   2017-05-01                    Черный       0.001296   чай               0.001520     0.001520
..         ...                       ...            ...   ...                    ...          ...
19  2017-07-01                    Черный       0.387125   чай               0.464413     0.464413
20  2017-07-01                   Зеленый       0.113402   чай               1.000000     1.000000
21  2017-07-01                Порошковый       0.026510   чай               1.000000     1.000000
22  2017-07-01                   Красный       0.013255   чай               1.000000     1.000000
23  2017-07-01                     Белый       0.013255   чай               1.000000     1.000000
24  2017-07-01                    Черный       0.000000   чай               0.000000     0.000000
25  2017-07-01                   Зеленый       0.000000   чай               0.000000     0.000000

[26 rows x 6 columns]
```